# Water leaking under the kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, leak

I have a water leak under the kitchen sink. There is no hot water line connected to a water heater. The cold water is leaking thru the concrete counter top where the hot water line connects to the faucet. Its a concrete counter top and I"ve tried patching it with white concrete and silicone but the water keeps seeping through the convrete  Wh

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Also, the situation is not clear - photos are always a big help.

Comment: Replace the seal on the faucet

Comment: Where is the water coming from?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information for an informed answer here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess based on no photos and not a very clear understanding of what is going on there. I get that the water is leaking out the hot side of the faucet but I am not at all sure what your set up is there.

I think you just need to cap off the hot water line coming **from** the faucet (which would normally supply hot water **to** the faucet)- there are many ways to do that- if you can even get to it through the thickness of your concrete countertop. If it is a single handle faucet then it seems like what is happening is if you turn the faucet on to anything other than pure cold water, it is running out the open hot side of the faucet. It is also possible that you have a 2 handle faucet and the seal on the hot valve is not working- allowing water to seep out (as intimated by the comment from @knowitall). This could be fixed by changing the valve cartridge in the faucet- If that is beyond your comfort zone then simply get a supply line that fits onto the faucet threads and cap off the end- (where it would normally connect to the hot water angle stop). Someone with basic plumbing knowledge at your favorite hardware store should be able to set you up with necessary parts for this.

Comment: Thank you I'll replace the cartrige on the hot water side. I have two handles on the faucet.